# Using function argument in JavaScript dot notation

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am using Handlebars for a site I am building for rendering the sites content and language control.
To make things easier I want to make a function where I can pass in the the "page" as an argument.

Here is the function I have started on:

```
config.renderLanguage = function(page) {
    var soruce = $('#body').html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(soruce);
    // "this" is my language file.
    $('#body').append(template(this.language_file.page.body));
};
```

I assume that it won't work because when "page" comes in, it is a string, resulting in an error.
So the question is really how I can convert the argument so it can be used in the dot notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot.

If you want to use variables, then you must use square bracket notation.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that :-) Do you have any idea on how I could go about this with a different approach?

Comment: Yes. Use square bracket notation.

Comment: Thats what you said before. Thanks :-)

Comment: That's because it is still the solution.